# Is there a wizard-like ui widget for Kendo like there is for asp.net ajax?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik-mvc

With the Telerik asp.net ajax library, there is a wizard control that wraps the behavior of stepping a user through a sequence of actions.  Is there anything similar with the Kendo library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. At this moment, there isn't a wizard component in Kendo UI. Here are the [demos](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/) of available components. The suggestion was made to Telerik to include a wizard component, but [it was declined](http://kendoui-feedback.telerik.com/forums/127393-telerik-kendo-ui-feedback/suggestions/2366288-wizard-control-plugin).

Comment: Thanks, thats the conclusion I come to also.  I think I seen it mentioned that it shouldnt be that difficult to construct something that does this type of functionality.